# indexedDB blocked DOM exception after an insert loop

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, domexception

I'm doing few tests with indexedDB and I keep getting chrome blocked during an insert test.
Basically what I'm doing is a simple loop, 100000 times, inserting simple string in the db. It completes correctly but at the end the indexedDB from the inspector is not visible. Not even refreshing the page. If trying to reload the page and reopening the database I get a DOM exception. If closing chrome it hangs and I have to kill it.

Below the code:

```
var testIndexedDB = {

  db : null,

  request: null,

  openDB : function(){
    var self = this;
    var request = this.request =  indexedDB.open("web", 1);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
      // The database did not previously exist, so create object stores and indexes.
      request.close();
      var db = request.result;
      var stories = db.createObjectStore("stories", {keyPath: "id"});

    };

    request.onsuccess = function() {
      self.db = request.result;
    };

     request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e);     
    };

    request.onblocked = function(e){
        console.log('blocked')
    }
  },

  addItem: function(store, loid, text){
    var db = this.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(store, "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore(store);
    var request = store.put({
      "id": loid,
      "text" : text
    });

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      // Re-render all the todo's

    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e.value);
    };
  },

  getItem: function(store, loid){
    var db = this.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(store);
    var store = trans.objectStore(store);
    var request = store.get(loid);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log(request.result) // Refresh the screen
    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    };
  },

  removeItem: function(store, loid){
    var db = this.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(store, "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore(store);
    var request = store.delete(loid);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log('el deleted'); // Refresh the screen
    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    };
  },

  testSize: function(){
    var i = 0,
        t;

    while(i<100000){
      t = new Date().getTime();
      this.addItem('stories', i, t)
      i++;

    }
    console.log('items added')
  }
};

testIndexedDB.openDB();
```

simply run `testIndexedDB.testSize()` to notice the issue.

How can I properly test continuos insertion and why is this happening?

thanks

Comment: 100,000 transactions is going to hurt. A lot.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem that you have in the batch insert is the fact that you are opening 100000 transaction and that blocks the database. I've made some optimizations to your code for batch inserting and now the insert time is less than 5s.

Instead of opening separate transaction for every item, I group the items in arrays of 1000 items and then open a transaction for that batch. Now the number of transaction is reduced to 100. Here are all the changes:

First I created a batch insert Function:

```
addItems: function(store, items){
    var db = this.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(store, "readwrite"); //uses only one transaction per batch of 1000
    trans.oncomplete = function(e){
        console.log('batch inserted');
    };
    var store = trans.objectStore(store);
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var request = store.put(items[i]);
        request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log(e.value);
        };
    }
},
```

And then I've changed the inserting function to send the data in batches:

```
testSize: function(){
    var i = 0,
    t;
    tempList = [];
    while(i<100000){
        t = new Date().getTime();
        tempList.push({
            "id": i,
            "text" : t
        })
        if(i> 0 && i% 1000 == 0){ //items are grouped into a array of 1000 items
            this.addItems('stories', tempList.slice());
            tempList = [];
        }      
        i++;
    }
    console.log('items added');
}
```